# Transfer .txt or .pdf files from a flutter application with the help of ble connection to another android mb

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

Flutter app that uses flutter_blue_plus package can scan and list the available [ble] devices. Is it possible to select one of the android mobile phone that has Bluetooth enabled ON detected? and is it possible to send a file or text or message saying "HI THERE" to the selected andoid phone from the flutter app itself?

I am very new to flutter and dart programming. But i recently came across this package and want to try to pass data or receive data from other devices using ble.

The response I get when I try to sent data: it does not work and I found while debugging that write is not enabled in the device.

Is it possible to establish a bluetooth pair and connect programmatically with the help of flutter_blue_plus package?

Kindly help in understanding the ble_flutter communication in the context of 2 android phones using a flutter app.

My understanding is that using flutter_blue_plus package, we can scan and find the list of nearby bluetooth active [enabled ON] devices.

```
 FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;

// Scan for Bluetooth devices
var scanSubscription = flutterBlue.scan().listen((scanResult) {
  // Get device information
  print('Device found: ${scanResult.device.name}');
});

// But using the latest package, name, id and some of the methods are all depreciated. 

// Connect to device
await device.connect();

// Read Battery Level characteristic
List<BluetoothService> services = await device.discoverServices();
services.forEach((service) {
  if(service.uuid.toString() == "0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb") {
    List<BluetoothCharacteristic> characteristics = service.characteristics;
    characteristics.forEach((characteristic) {
      if (characteristic.uuid.toString() == "00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb") {
        characteristic.read().then((value) {
          int batteryLevel = value[0];
          print("Battery level is $batteryLevel %");
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

1. Does each android phones do have these BluetoothServices and Guid values that are different and unique for each devices?
2. How do I establish a bluetooth connection from the android phone that uses the ble_flutter_app to another android phone? Is it possible to ask for permission to connect or transfer data to it?

I am not an android developer nor mobile application developer. I dont have much understanding of android backend development.

Comment: So basically you want to send data from one device to another irrespective of that device is using this package or not right ?

Comment: "My understanding is that using flutter_blue_plus package, we can scan and find the list of nearby bluetooth active [enabled ON] devices." No, you find devices that are advertising. A mobile phone with activated Bluetooth does not show if it does not have any App installed that advertises as a BLE peripheral.

Comment: Suppose there is a flutter application that has a list of mobilephones [ bluetooth ON], Is it possible to establish a connection and send a file from the phone's download folder to the other device [Bluetooth ON from the list].???

Comment: Using BLE only if you have an App running on the other device that can handle a file stream. What you want to do sounds more like a task for Bluetooth Classic to me